# Multi column sort in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there any possibility for multiple sorting in Power BI. I have below table

```
**employee_name**   **status**     **Status_Count**  **Duration**
 Arun prasath          closed             2                116
 Arun prasath          open               3                565
 Arun prasath          unattended         6                1140
 Sudip                 closed             1                46
 saran                 closed             2                67
```

Now below is the criterias;

```
  i) Filter the closed status

 ii) Top status count

iii) Shortest time duration
```

Expected table output :

```
**employee_name**   **status**     **Status_Count**  **Duration**
 saran                 closed             2                67
 Arun prasath          closed             2                116
 Sudip                 closed             1                46
```

Can anybody help me??

Comment: Kindly help me to solve this

Comment: Try creating a `Rank` column using the `RANKX()` function and then sort name by rank.

Comment: Can u please give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the query editor with this formula:

`= Table.Sort(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Status", Order.Ascending},{"Status_count", Order.Descending},{"Duration", Order.Descending}})`

Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: I am new in power bi.Can you please tell the steps  for  using this query.

Comment: 1) Goto Edit Queries 2) Sort the table by "Status" 3) Go to option "Advanced Editor" 4) Manually append rules to existing sort rule.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually below steps was done by me,

1)Table "customers" contains the column "status"
2)Using "New measure" I calculated the status count and named the column as "status 
   count".
3)Using the two columns "created date" and "updated date" I calculated the duration 
   period as named the columns as "Duration"(using New Measure).
4)And table "tses" contains the column "Employee name".

Comment: Now by your answer, when I go to "Edit queries", there the two columns "Status Count" and "Duration" is not visible . That tables are visible only in fields of visualization page

In Visualization field,

table:customers :(contains): --> status, status count, Duration
table:tses :(contains):--> Employee name 
In this case what I want to do??